# Parsing API Response To See if All Sku Tags are Present

Tags: c#, api

I am fairly new to c# and am trying to parse an api response. My goal is to check each sku present to see if it contains all three of the following tags: Dot, Low, and Default. The only thing is the api is set up a bit odd, so even if the "Rskuname" is the same, its listed under a different skuID. I need to make sure each Rskuname contains all of the 3 types, here is an example of the api below (parts of it have been omitted since its a huge amount of data, just showing the pieces important to this question)

```
"Skus": [
    {
      "SkuId": "DH786HY",
      "Name": "Stand_D3_v19 Dot",
      "Attributes": {
        "RSkuName": "Stand_D3_v19",
        "Category": "General",
        "DiskSize": "0 Gb",
        "Low": "False",
      },
      "Tags": [
        "Dot"
{
      "SkuId": "DU70PLL1",
      "Name": "Stand_D3_v19",
      "Attributes": {
        "Attributes": {
        "RSkuName": "Stand_D3_v19",
        "Category": "General",
        "DiskSize": "0 Gb",
        "Low": "False",
      },
      "Tags": [
        "Default"
      ]
{
      "SkuId": "DPOK65R4",
      "Name": "Stand_D3_v19 Low",
      "Attributes": {
        "Attributes": {
        "RSkuName": "Stand_D3_v19",
        "Category": "General",
        "DiskSize": "0 Gb",
        "Low": "True",
      },
      "Tags": [
        "Low"
      ],
{
      "SkuId": "DPOK65R4",
      "Name": "Stand_D6_v22 Low",
      "Attributes": {
        "Attributes": {
        "RSkuName": "Stand_D6_v22",
        "Category": "General",
        "DiskSize": "0 Gb",
        "Low": "True",
      },
      "Tags": [
        "Low"
      ],
```

Originally I tried to iterate through each sku, however since the skuids are different even though the name is the same that doesnt work. I was thinking of possibly using a string, hashset dictionary so it would go skuName:Tags but I'm not sure that will work either. Any ideas would be much appreciated. Apologies if this question isn't phrased well, once again I'm a beginner. I have included what I tried originally below:

```
foreach (Sku sku in skus)
                {
                    string SkuName = sku.Attributes[RSkuName];
                   
                    var count = 0;
                        
                            if (sku.Tags.Equals(Default))
                            {
                                count++;
                            }
                            if (sku.Tags.Equals(Low))
                            {
                                count++;
                            }
                           if (sku.Tags.Equals(Dot))
                            {
                                count++;
                            }
                        }
                     if (count < 3)
                        {
                            traceSource.TraceInformation($"There are not 3 tags present for" {SkuName} );
                        }
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome here, is this a simple true/false for the entire `skus` array, or do you need a list of all the valid and or invalid SKUs? It is similar logic to achieve both outcomes, but to write as a truthy statement could be significantly shorter.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I need a list of all of the invalid skus

Answer (score 0):

Seems simple:

1. group by `RSkuName`
2. group by `Tag` element value
3. make sure there is a group for each of the required tag values.

Yes you could use a hashset in this scenario to formulate the groups. If we had to do it from first principals that that's not a bad idea.

However we can use the LINQ fluent `GroupBy` function (which uses a hashset internally) to iterate over the groups.

There is only one complicating factor to this that even your first attempt does not take into account, `Tags` is an *array* of strings, so to properly group the values across multiple arrays so we can use `GroupBy` we can use the `SelectMany` function to merge the arrays from multiple SKUs into a single set, then `GroupBy` becomes viable again.

Finally, if the only possible values for `Tag` elements are `Dot`, `Low`, and `Default`. Then we only need to count the groups and make sure there are 3 to make the SKU valid.

```
bool notValid = skus.GroupBy(x => x.Attributes[RSkuName])
                    .Any(sku => sku.SelectMany(x => x.Tags)
                                   .GroupBy(x => x)
                                   .Count() < 3)
```

> I call this a **fail fast** approach, instead of making sure **ALL** items satisfy the criteria we only try to detect the first time that the criteria is not met and stop processing the list

If other tags might be provided then we can still use similar syntax by filtering the tags first:

```
string[] requiredTags = new string [] { "Dot", "Low", "Default" };
bool notValid = skus.GroupBy(x => x.Attributes[RSkuName])
                    .Any(sku => sku.SelectMany(x => x.Tags)
                                   .Where(x => requiredTags.Contains(x))
                                   .GroupBy(x => x)
                                   .Count() < 3)
```

If you need to list out all the skus that have failed, and perhaps *why* they were not valid, then we can do that with similar syntax. Instead of using LINQ though, lets look at how you might do this with your current iterator approach...

Start by creating a class to hold the tags that we have seen for each sku:

```
public class SkuTracker
{
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tags { get;set; } = new List<string>();
    public override string ToString() => $"{Sku} - ({Tags.Count()}) {String.Join(",", Tags)}";
}
```

Then we maintain a dictionary of these `SkuTracker` objects and record the tags as we see them:

```
var trackedSkus = new Dictionary<string, SkuTracker>();
...
foreach (Sku sku in skus)
{
    string skuName = sku.Attributes[RSkuName];
    if (!trackedSkus.ContainsKey(skuName))
        trackedSkus.Add(skuName, new SkuTracker { Sku = skuName }; 
    trackedSkus.Tags.AddRange(sku.Tags);
}
...

var missingSkus = trackedSkus.Values.Where(x => x.Tags.Count() < 3)
                                    .ToList();  
foreach(var sku in missingSkus)
{
    traceSource.TraceInformation($"There are not 3 tags present for {sku.Sku}" );
}
```

Looking at the JSON fragment you have provided, I suspect that you could only verify the validation *after* the entire list was processed, so we cannot trace out the failure messages in the first iteration, this current code will still produce the same output as if we had though.

> **NOTE:** In the `SkuTracker` we have defined the `ToString()` override, this is so that you could easily view the content of the tracked SKUs in the debugger using the native viewers, especially if you try to inspect the content of `missingSkus`.